# Opening Command Prompt in Python using Autoit

Tags: python, autoit

I'm fairly new to coding and was wanting to open CMD to run commands in it.

```
    import autoit
import time

autoit.run("cmd.exe")
autoit.win_wait_active("[CLASS:Command]", 3)
autoit.control_send("[CLASS:Command]", "Edit1", "hello world{!}")
```

I just want to load CMD and run a command in it of my choice.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

You can try using `subprocess` module -

```
import subprocess
p = subprocess.Popen(["start", "cmd", "/k", "Command_Here"], shell = True)
```